# React Type error cannot read properties of null even though its not null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, typeerror

code image

[image: 1]

this  is my first question on stackoverflow please help me out. Thanks.
I am trying to simply print out the state property in a div element:

```
super();
this.state = {
  city: "New York"
};
```

and then i try to print it out in a div element like this:

```
{this.state.city}
```

but it gives me the error
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'city')
even though its not null

Comment: try `{this.state?.city}`

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say what the problem is. Can you update your question to include the entire component?

Comment: Could you share the structure of the class component? N.B. React documentation says this **Class components should always call the base constructor with props.** https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html E.g. `super(props)`

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough code. I have uploaded a picture of the code

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the state that is defined in the `Main` component. Move the constructor to the `App` component.

Comment: Thank you sooo muchhh man!! i have been stuck at this for 2 hours.